# Setup version for module 'Namespace_Modulename' is not specified : Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module

I am creating an module in **Magento 2 ( ver. 2.0.0)**. I have registered my module in **app/etc/config.xml**

```
'Namespace_Modulename => 1,
```

My `module.xml` file under **app/code/Namespace/Modulename/etc/module.xml**

**module.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="Namespace_Modulename" setup_version="2.0.1"/> 
</config>
```

When I run my module Magento 2 generate below error :

> Setup version for module 'Namespace_Modulename' is not specified

My module was working fine before stable release, after upgraded to stable release I start getting this error. I searched lot on google before adding here, got some results but none of then working for me.

Kindly guide me where I am doing wrong.

Comment: i guess `setup_version` is magento version, not module version. Try 2.0.0

Comment: Thanks for reply, I just replaced the `setup_version` with 2.0.0 but still getting the same error

Comment: I have one more query, if `setup_verion` is magento version then where we specify module version?

Comment: as far as i'm aware `setup_version="1.0.0"` is the module version

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will also need to create a `registration.php` file to register your module:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Namespace_Modulename',
    __DIR__
);
```

In `app/code/Namespace/Modulename/registration.php`.

Also you shouldn't need to manually change `app/etc/config.xml` after you have created a `app/code/Namespace/Modulename/moudle.xml` and `registration.php` running `bin/magento module:enable Namespace_Modulename` will update this for you.

A good blog here for the full process https://www.ashsmith.io/magento2/module-from-scratch-module-part-1-setup/

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful for me, this resolve my issue

Comment: Now I am getting another error :
Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory. 
The following modules are outdated:
Namespace_Modulename schema: current version - none, required version - 1.0.0
Namespace_Modulename data: current version - none, required version - 1.0.0

Comment: have you then tried running `bin/magento setup:upgrade` ?

Comment: When i run this command in terminal I got : [InvalidArgumentException]                               
  There are no commands defined in the "setup" namespace.

Comment: try updating your namespaceSchema in your `module.xml` to `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd"`

Answer (score 1):

Try this in module.xml:

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="Namespace_Modulename" schema_version="2.0.1" setup_version="2.0.1"/> 
</config>`

Add registration.php and composer.json in your module.

/app/code/Namespace/Module/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Namespace_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

/app/code/Namespace/Module/composer.json

```
{
    "name": "namespace/module",
    "description": "namespace",
    "require": {
      "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
      "magento/framework": "100.0.*",
      "magento/module-ui": "100.0.*",
      "magento/module-config": "100.0.*",
      "magento/module-contact": "100.0.*"    
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "100.0.0",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "extra": {
        "map": [
            [
                "*",
                "Namespace/Module"
            ]
        ]
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [ "registration.php" ],
        "psr-4": {
            "namespace\\module\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Now run `magento setup:upgrade` and schema upgrade if applicable.

Now clear all caches and var/generation folder. `Login to admin panel > Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced`. Your module should be listed here now.