# How to setup a new custom module in Magento2

Tags: module, magento2, extensions, compiler

I added a new module to `config.php`, then I ran `php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade`

This is what I got:`"Please re-run Magento compile command"`
And the module I added gets deleted from `config.php`

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 1):

For this run the compile command first - `php magento setup:di:compile` and then run the upgrade command `php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade`.

Also, please ensure that you have `registration.php` and `composer.json` included in your module. More details on the same here: [Setup version for module 'Namespace_Modulename' is not specified : Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91171/setup-version-for-module-namespace-modulename-is-not-specified-magento-2/91216#91216)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this manual to create your module:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/build.html